# how to securely use secretAccessKey on react JS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, security

I have a little react.js app that sends an email to AWS SES.

It is working fine, but now im concerned about security, on exposing this code as a web site on the internet, I understand there are bots looking for

> secretAccessKey

how to handle the secrets that I need on my js file?

```
  AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: 'keykeykey',
      secretAccessKey: 'secret/access/key',
      region: 'us-east-1'
    });
```

Comment: Using secret keys in front-end is not recommended. You should use your own server to send emails instead of sending directly from the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Hardcoding Access Key and Secret Access Key, You can set Access Key and Secret Access Key in Environment variable and give path of an environment variable. Please have a read about IAM best Security Practices once before doing this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#delegate-using-roles

Answer (score 1):

You may use that by encrypt the key by using 'AES' or some else. Hope it is useful